# How to check String contains one of Strings in collection

Tags: java, string, collections

I want to check if the target string contains string in collections. And match the longest one. E.g.

Target string: `str = "eignelaiwgn"`

Collection strings: `eig`, `a`, `eb`, `eigne`, `eignep`

The result needs to be `eigne`

First I thought HashMap, but it is not sorted. So I try to put collection strings into ArrayList, then sort the list with string length. Then use `for each` loop to check

```
if ( str.contains("eigne") )
```

This needs to loop list each time. Is there a better(faster) way to achieve this?

Comment: You can use binary search technique after sorting the Arraylist to find the solution in log(n) time

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java, return if List contains String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16218863/java-return-if-list-contains-string)

Comment: @Lemmy , probable not. I want to check if target string contians string that in Collections. Not if the collection contains the target string.

Answer (score 2):

Seems pretty straightforward with streams:

```
String targetString = "eignelaiwgn";
Collection<String> collection = Arrays.asList("eig", "a", "eb", "eigne", "eignep");

Optional<String> longestMatch = collection.stream()
    .filter(targetString::contains)
    .max(Comparator.comparingInt(String::length));

longestMatch.ifPresent(System.out::println); // eigne
```

This reads as: *For every string in the collection, check if the target string contains it. If true, return the string with the max length. (As the collection might be empty, or as no string in the collection might match the filter, `max` returns an `Optional<String>`)*.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `TreeSet` for the same.

```
String str = "eignelaiwgn";
// Assuming that the 'sub-strings' are stored in a list
List<String> myList = Arrays.asList("eig", "a", "eb", "eigne", "eignep");

// Create a TreeSet that sorts based on descending order of length
Set<String> treeSet = new TreeSet<>((a, b) -> b.length() - a.length());
treeSet.addAll(myList);

String containsSub = treeSet.stream().filter(e -> str.contains(e))
                            .findFirst()
                            .orElse("Not found");
```

Now we iterate over the `TreeSet` and find the *first* occurrence where the sub-string is present in the original string. Now since the `TreeSet` is sorted in descending order of length, iteration will start from the highest to the lowest.

Comment: Why are you using `TreeMap` instead of `TreeSet`?

Comment: Ironically, I was just thinking of changing that while having lunch! Guess you beat me to it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use LevensteinDistance() method of StringUtils class in java which will tell you the number of changes needed to change one String into another.you can print string with minimum changes needed, which is your answer. see this document -> [LevenshteinDistance](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html)

Also look for differences method for same class which will tell the difference between the two string.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a suffix tree. Please follow this link:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pattern-searching-using-suffix-tree/

Comment: More explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9452701/ukkonens-suffix-tree-algorithm-in-plain-english?rq=1